# How do I delete multiple lines in a text file with python?

Tags: python

I am practicing my python skills by writing a Phone book program. I am able to search and add entries but I am having a lot of trouble deleting entries.

I am trying to find a line that matches my search and delete it as well as the next 4 lines. I have a function to delete here:

```
def delete():
    del_name = raw_input("What is the first name of the person you would like to delete? ")
    with open("phonebook.txt", "r+") as f:
            deletelines = f.readlines()
            for i, line in enumerate(deletelines):
                if del_name in line:
                    for l in deletelines[i+1:i+4]:
                        f.write(l)
```

This does not work.

How would I delete multiple entries from a text file like this?

Comment: Do you want remove multiple entries with the same name, is that right?

Comment: I want to remove a line that I search for and the next 4 lines after it.

Comment: So, each entry has 5 lines?

Comment: Yep each entry has 5 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your direct question: you can use `fileinput` to easily alter a text file in-place:

```
import fileinput
file = fileinput.input('phonebook.txt', inplace=True)

for line in file:
     if word_to_find in line:
         for _ in range(4): # skip this line and next 4 lines
             next(file, None)
     else:
         print line,
```

In order to avoid reading the entire file into memory, this handles some things in the background for you - it moves your original file to a tempfile, writes the new file, and then deletes the tempfile.

Probably better answer: it looks like you have rolled a homemade serialization solution.  Consider using a built-in library like `csv`, `json`, `shelve`, or even `sqlite3` to persist your data in an easier-to-work-with format.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks for the help!

The only problem it is giving me is matching anything in a line. So if i have test and test2 they will both be deleted.

Comment: @ChrisJones then you'll need to be more sophisticated about your matching, using `re.search`.  I can't help you write that since I don't know the format of your file or the thing that you're searching for.

Comment: I thought this was working but it deletes everything after it finds a match, not just the 5 lines. 

I didn't think to use regular expressions. I will give that a try. Thanks again.

Comment: if you have a file called phonebook.txt.bak in the same directory, won't this delete it?