# How can I delete multipe lines in a text by Python?

Tags: python

I have a similar question to [delete multiple line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815373/how-do-i-delete-multiple-lines-in-a-text-file-with-python)

I want to delete the line and the next 4 lines. This is my code:

```
bind = open('/etc/bind/named.conf.local','r')
a = dict['name']
for line in bind:
        if a in line:
            print('line  exist')
            ''' and delete this line and 4 line after it'''
        else:
            print('line does not exist')
```

I want to save modify text in /etc/bind/named.conf.local in place, without fileinput. I do not want **skip** 4 line I want to delete them from the file. I do not want to read it and write it again and skip 4 lines.

What should I do?

Comment: Why you don't want use fileinput?

Comment: I think it should have very simple approach.

Comment: `fileinput` is the simplest one

Comment: You should include an example input and expected output.

Comment: get 10 number in 10 lines and delete 5-6-7-8 and i want to tell program that delete 5 and 3 line after it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following code does what you're looking for. You will have to adjust settings `filename`, `keyword` and `delete` to your needs. The code will delete `delete` lines from file `filename` every time `keyword` is found in a line. (Including the `keyword` line.)

```
# Settings
filename = "test.txt"
keyword = "def"
delete = 2

# Read lines from file
with open(filename) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# Process lines
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if keyword in line:
        del lines[i:i + delete]

# Save modified lines to file
with open(filename, "w") as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```

Example `test.txt` before:

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
```

Example `test.txt` afterwards:

```
abc
jkl
```

Comment: might be more clear to just set `skip = 4` instead of incrementing

Comment: I do not want skip 4 line i want delete them

Answer (score 0):

It all boils down to keeping a skip count that you initialize with the first occurrence of the matching line and increase afterward:

```
match = "text line to match"
with open('input.txt','r') as lines:
    with open('output.txt','w') as output:
        skip = -1
        for line in lines:
            skip += skip >= 0 or skip < 0 and line.strip("\n") == match
            if skip not in range(5): 
                output.write(line)
```

If what you're trying to avoid is reading lines one by one, you could write it like this (but you still need to open the files)

```
match    = "text line to match"
lines    = open('input.txt','r').read().split("\n")
matchPos = lines.index(match)
del lines[matchPos:matchPos+5]
open('output.txt','w').write("\n".join(lines))
```

Comment: I do not want to skip lin and print .I want delete them and save it

Comment: @yasinlachini then use `fileinput` or write each line (except for the ones you skip) to a [`tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html) and then `.replace` the original with the temp file

Comment: Skipping lines when writing the output is equivalent to deleting them. I adjusted my example to better illustrate this.

Comment: I do not want use fileinput

Comment: @yasinlachini that doesn't sound rational

Comment: I don't know of a way to read from one file and write to another without opening the files.  Perhaps what you are looking for is a shell script that does something like `cat input.txt | grep a-regular-expression > output.txt` but that's not using Python at all.

Comment: I can delete one line without fileinput i want a way to delete multiple line.

Comment: you read a line and then write it. I want to read line and delete some of them not read and write them exept some line

Comment: Show us the code you use to do that and we will be able to better help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `fileinput`, you can also read all the lines of your file, write them (except for the lines you skip using `next(f)`) to a [`tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) and replace the original file with the temporary file.

```
from pathlib import Path
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

named_conf = Path('/etc/bind/named.conf.local')

with open(named_conf) as infile:
    with NamedTemporaryFile("w", delete=False) as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            if line_should_be_deleted(line):
                # skip this line and the 4 lines after it
                for _ in range(4):
                    next(infile)
            else:
                outfile.write(line)

Path(outfile.name).replace(named_conf)
```

But you should just use `fileinput`, like the answer to the question you linked to says, since it does the tempfile stuff for you.

Answer (score -3):

```
bind = open('/etc/bind/named.conf.local','r')
textfile = bind.readlines()
a = 'some text'
for line_num in range(len(textfile)):
    try:
        if a in textfile[line_num]:
            print('line exists')
            del textfile[line_num:line_num+5]
    except IndexError:
        break
writer = open("/etc/bind/named.conf.local","w")
writer.write(''.join(textfile))
writer.close()
```

Comment: I get this error  AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: after delete 4 line i want to  save it

Comment: You need to store them in a variable and then do this. While reading the lines do `readlines+=line`

Comment: just print textfile. del operator will modify the list

Comment: Check my solution @yasinlachini, this is posted after your recent edit.

Comment: I get this error AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: This may be because you have made mistake in naming the variable. Try to split the string, not the file object

Comment: @SmartManoj what if 'a' exists in the last line of file? Why did you edit my answer?

Comment: `IndexError `arises only at last in this case and you added `break` outside except

Comment: But it will not delete the line. My solution will delete the line and exits the loop

Comment: `IndexError` arises only at last, the line does not delete anything and that `break` would replace only one instance.

Comment: last before line is -2 ; Just `print(textfile[line_num:]) ` in except;

Comment: That is what i did. But you removed it and put break statement Manoj

Comment: try should be above `if`

Answer (score -3):

```
bind = open('text.txt','r')
a = dict['name']
lines = bind.readlines()
i = 0
while i < len(lines):
    if a in lines[i]:
        del lines[i:i+5]
    i += 1
print(lines)
```

Comment: I do not want skip 4 line i want delete them

Comment: it complie without error and seem it should work but it does not delete lines